# How to load controllers in AngularJS dynamically?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have many controllers in app and I don't want to load them upfront as the combined JS becomes very heavy.

So I have tried following:

In my main `app.js`, I have route defined as below:

```
$routeProvider.when('/myaccount', {
    templateUrl: 'my-account.html',
    title: 'My Account'
})
```

The `my-account-controller.js` has controller defined like:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('my-account', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
    $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

And finally in `my-account.html`, I have a script tag which should load the controller syncronously before using it. I am attaching that contorller with `ng-controller` directive:

```
script src='/assets/my-account-controller.js'
<div class="container" ng-controller='my-account'>
   ...
</div>
```

The problem is somehow, Angular can not identify `my-account` as controller and it throws following error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'my-account' is not a function, got undefined
```

Can someone tell me what is the missing piece?

Comment: did you find a way to do so though? I also have a same problem

Answer (score 1):

You should use UpperCamelCase in your controller name, and i don't know if you already have defined `myApp`, if yes, you should remove the second argument from the module method since it will reset the dependencies:

so this -> `angular.module('myApp',[])` should be -> `angular.module('myApp')`

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyAccount', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
    $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

And in your view:

```
<script src='/assets/my-account-controller.js'
<div class="container" ng-controller='MyAccount'>
   ...
</div>
```

And the route:

```
$routeProvider.when('/myaccount', {
    templateUrl: 'my-account.html',
    title: 'My Account',
    controller: 'MyAccount'
});
```

You can read more about angular best practices [here](https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide)

Comment: @MitulShah check my edit regarding the dependencies, I believe you should not be passing the second argument there.

Comment: The only problem here is I don't want to specify the controller inside route file as there are many controllers.

So I am using `ng-controller` directive for that in HTML, _after_ loading the `my-account-controller.js` with `script` tag, but somehow Angular is still not able to identify that as controller.


Maybe we need it specified before hand?

Comment: did you try removing the second parameter from the module method? the empty array. try removing it please.

Comment: Yes, I removed them. I think the problem here is: I have a `script` tag inside the template, which is not executed. And so effectively `my-account-controller.js` is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the proper way to do it. You have to declare your controller in the route you are using such as

```
$routeProvider.when(''/myaccount'', {
              templateUrl: 'my-account.html',
              controller: 'my-account',
              title: 'My Account'
})
```

Comment: Yes, but in that case I have to load `my-account` (plus all other) controller in that file, which is something I don't want.

Comment: I don't think so. If for each view you have one controller this is the best way to do it. Moreover, the proper way to name a controller (according to AngularJs documentation) would be MyAccountController in your case. You should start with that.

Comment: Yes, I tried to specify `MyAccount` as controller without loading that in this file which throws an error. I have already renamed the controller.